# Dynamically add <asp:content to page, Nested masterpages

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I am currently using nested masterpages in my latest asp.net 4.0 project and i want to change the look and feel dynamically, so the homepage may just be 1 column wide, about us page may be 2 columns etc.

I am dynamically loading the masterpage dependant on the record selected in the DB (1column.master, 2column.master) on the pre_init event of a static page (Load.aspx)  which work succesfully however i need to be able to dynamically add  controls to the page in order to get the desired layout.

Is this possible, is there a better way of achieveing this?

Please inform me if you need more information / or have any questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> however i need to be able to dynamically add controls to the page in order to get the desired layout. Is this possible, is there a better way of achieveing this?

Yes it is possible. The tricky thing about adding dynamic controls to ASP.NET webpages (master, content, whatever) is that the controls must be **recreated** each postback to the server. This is the combersome part.  You can't just modify your page by dynamically adding controls, and expect them to exist the next time there is a postback to the server. This includes not only the control but all of its properties like ID, etc.

For some more information take a look to the following link:

**Dynamic Web Server Controls and View State:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx

**Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET**
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx